# MySQLi query fails after refreshing page

Tags: php, cookies, hash

I'm learning PHP, I currently practice prodecural programming and I have one problem. I'm building "remember me" functionality for my web site based on hashing cookie value, it contains two values, identifier + hashed identifier, I store that in cookie and I split identifier and hashed identifier in two different database rows in user's table. In checking pase I split cookie in array so I can separate identifier and hashed identifier and make commparison to DB, first check is ok but my problem is after I refresh page second time my query outputs empty string so `hash_equals` function fails.

Here is my code:

remembering user:

```
/*
    * if user checked "remember me" checkbox create cookie and update info in table 
    */
    if ($userRemember === "on") {

        $rememberID = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));
        $rememberToken = hash('sha512', $rememberID);
        updateRememberInfo($rememberID, $rememberToken, $userName);
        setcookie("verificationToken", "{$rememberID}___{$rememberToken}", time() + 60 * 60, '/', 'localhost', false, true);
    }
```

checking user info from cookie and DB

```
function checkRememberInfo() {
    /*
    * include DB connection
    */
    global $connection;

    /*
    * checking if cookie exists
    */
    if (isset($_COOKIE["verificationToken"])) {

        /*
        * geting data from cookie
        * spliting data in two strings, i used triple underscore to split values in cookie
        */
        $data = $_COOKIE["verificationToken"];
        $credentials = explode("___", $data);

        /*
        * if cookie is empty or data from cookie isn't split in two array items redirect to index page
        */
        if (empty(trim($data)) || count($credentials) !== 2) {

            header("Location: index.php");
        /*
        * else perform query and check values from DB and cookie
        */
        } else {

            $identifier = $credentials[0];
            $hashedToken = hash('sha512', $credentials[1]);

            $query = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT `ID`, `username`, `rememberID`, `rememberToken` FROM `users` WHERE `rememberID` = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $identifier);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $userID, $userName, $rememberID, $rememberToken);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($query);
            mysqli_stmt_close($query);

            if (hash_equals($hashedToken, $rememberToken)) {

                // log user in

            } else {
                updateRememberInfo(null, null, $userName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can understand me and my problem, English is not my mother tongue.

**EDIT:**

I have solved the problem, in checkRememberInfo() function I was hashing already hashed part of cookie, that was wrong.

Comment: Output `$hashedToken`, `$rememberToken`, see what's the difference between'em

Comment: I have solved the problem, in checkRememberInfo() function I was hashing already hashed part of cookie.

Thanks anyway!!